How to properly use a 'for' loop inside a Firebird 2.5 procedure?
I know Firebird 2.5 is deprecated, but that's what's running on the project I'm working with. I need to build a procedure where a for loop is executed, but I can't make it work.
Here's a sample code: 
CREATE procedure SAMPLE
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE i INTEGER;
BEGIN
    
    FOR i = 1 TO 4 DO
    BEGIN
        FOR
            SELECT * FROM TABLE
        DO
            SUSPEND;
    END
END

When I execute this code, I always receive errors related to "invalid token". On the code above, I received:
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 7, column 9.
i. 

How can I properly use this for loop?

What makes you think that Firebird has a for loop that works like that?

There is no FOR loop syntax that allows you to iterate using an INTEGER variable, like you are trying to do.  The FOR loop syntax only supports iterating result sets.  Per the 2.5 Language Reference documentation, there are only 2 forms of FOR loop available:
FOR SELECT

7.6.11. FOR SELECT
Available in. PSQL
Used for. Looping row-by-row through a selected result set
Syntax
FOR <select_stmt> [AS CURSOR cursorname]
  DO <compound_statement>


FOR EXECUTE

7.6.12. FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT
Available in. PSQL
Used for. Executing dynamically created SQL statements that return a row set
Syntax
  FOR <execute_statement> DO <compound_statement>


For what you are trying to accomplish, you need to use a WHILE loop instead:

7.6.6. WHILE …​ DO
Used for. Looping constructs
Available in. PSQL
Syntax
WHILE <condition> DO
  <compound_statement>


For example:
CREATE procedure SAMPLE
AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE i INTEGER;
BEGIN
    
    i = 1;
    WHILE (i <= 4) DO
    BEGIN
        FOR
            SELECT * FROM TABLE
        DO
            SUSPEND;
        i = i + 1;
    END
END


I don't have Firebird at hand to play with but you need to have some result set to loop over with for, e.g.
for select 1 from rdb$database union select 2 from rdb$database union select 3 from rdb$database union select 4 from rdb$database do ...

or
with range (i) as (
  select 1 from rdb$database
  union all
  select r.i + 1 from range r
  where r.i < 4
)
for select i from range do ...

